A military space Saga with a woman who is a brilliant tactician and strategist
I only read, about 20 years ago, a few of the novels of what I think is a very large space Saga.
The galaxy is divided into several polities. But the Saga is mostly about two of them, one which is obviously based on late 18th Century France during the Revolutionary Terror, and the other one on the UK at that time. A monarchy where the monarch has a lot of power, but is "enlightened".
The main character is a woman officer in the Space Fleet of the monarchy. She is extremely brilliant and has a talent to "snatch victory from the jaws of defeat".
I forgot most of the details except one: she comes from a planet where there is another sentient species. So sentient that it should not really be called an animal. So they are not pets, but some of them choose to "bond" with a particular human. Few humans, even native of that planet, are chosen, but it is the case of this officer. These bonds are extremely strong, it is not uncommon that, when the human dies, the sentient that had chosen him or her dies of despair.

This is almost certainly the Honor Harrington series by David Weber. The series begins with On Basilisk Station, published in 1993, and is now up to at least 14 novels, plus short fiction and other works based in the universe (known as the "Honorverse").
The central character is Honor Harrington, a highly talented officer serving in the space navy of the Kingdom of Manticore. The navy is consciously based on the Hornblower novels of C.S. Forester, with Manticore playing the role of England during the Napoleonic Wars. A major antagonist of the Kingdom is the Republic of Haven, which Weber based loosely on Napoleon's French Republic (with motifs like Haven's "Committee of Public Safety" echoing the "Comité de salut public" which governed France during the Reign of Terror.)
Harrington has a sentient pet called a treecat, from the planet Sphinx in the Manticore system. These animals can communicate telepathically, and Harrington's pet, Nimitz, frequently assists her in her duties. The bonding between a human and a treecat is extremely strong, and if the human dies the treecat often pines away later, committing suicide by starvation and dehydration.

Yes, this is exactly it. Napoleon came to power years after the "Comité de Salut Public" was dismantled (and mostly beheaded) by the Thermidorian Reaction but yes, a long Saga looks more like the Napoleonic wars with the Terror still in power.

"Hornblower" is lacking an "r", do you want to include it? (Fun tidbit: somewhere in the series, Harrington is reading a novel set in the Napoleonic era and is amused at seeing a main character with the initials HH. Quite a bit of fourth wall breaking going on here.)

Further, this memory was clearly from the earlier entries in the series, where The Republic of Haven was the antagonist. In the last decade or so of releases, the new antagonist has been a shadowy conspiracy run by a large corporation from within the galaxy's largest spacefaring nation. Haven has become a bit of an ally.

@T.E.D. Indeed, I only read a few among the first novels.

@Alfred - As a protip, sometimes some of the books are available for free online in the Baen Free library, although at the moment it looks like they only have the first 2. Also I know in the past I've found buying a hardback of one of the later entries netted me an "Honorverse" CD with the previous books in the series on it. Failing that, you can probably catch up (if you want to) at your local public library. Financially, that beats the heck out of buying 14 books.

Maybe it's just me not having read Hornblower and not being familiar with French history, but Haven always reminded me of the Soviet Union... I'm not sure I'd dare call a treecat a "pet", though.

@T.E.D. Thabks for the advice. Catching up would be a  nice idea.

@ilkkachu - A lot of people with cats would say that the cat considers the person the pet. Treecats are basically that concept ratcheted up a couple of notches.

@ilkkachu  Re: treecats Please note that in my question I did write that treecats (though I did not remember how they were called) were not pets. It is Clara Diaz Sanchez who called them pets in her answer. I disagree, but it was not  sufficient reason not to accept her answer ! lol

@T.E.D. Re : treecats LOL !

@ilkkachu Re: Soviet Union. You are right, the Comité de Salut Public of the French Revolution had a lot in common with the Presidium of the Supreme Soviet. The main difference is that the latter lasted for decades till 1989 while the former lasted about 16 months.
